# Set width in xml but height in code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can I set the width of a view (textview for example) in xml, but define its height programmatically, i havent seen anything in the android developer docs and was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in xml:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="HelloWorld"/>
```

And this one in your Class:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_view_height);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

dimens xml:

```
<dimen name="text_view_height">60dp</dimen>
```